# Make a cron task in Plesk 11.5 by API RPC

Tags: cron, rpc, plesk

I would like to schedule a task on Plesk 11.5 using [its API](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.1/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/index.htm?fileName=28784.htm) but I can't find how to do it: in the reference I linked it seems there is no api call to make cron jobs.

So, is it possible to create a scheduled task using the Plesk API? If not, is it possible to create automatically a scheduled task on domain creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no such command in API-RPC.
You can suggest this idea at UserVoice:  https://plesk.uservoice.com/

Comment: I posted a suggestion. Thanks.